# part identification

Tags: components, identification, datasheet

If possible. I would like a datasheet for the large IC pictured here, I havent found anything on google yet, seaching:MXICZ101061

[image]

Comment: Try googling 25L512

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important part is the second line. That's a [Macronix International Co. MX25L512](http://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/2434/MX25L512,%203V,%20512Kb,%20v1.7.pdf) 512kb serial flash.

A standard SPI eeprom. 25L almost always suggests SPI eeprom, 24L are i2c.